# Comment deleted - automatically?

Tags: discussion

I've just added a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042493/jquery-timer-that-checks-database-flag) along the lines of this (from memory) which has been deleted.

> The problem is that by asking if something is possible, you're effectively saying "please do it for me" (http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Learn about AJAX, how to write it in jQuery, and how to handle it in ASP.NET, and you'll have your solution.

Why was it deleted?  Was it done automatically, because it was flagged?  What was seen as wrong with it?

Is it to do with the use of the website?  (If so, I've pointed maybe people to it before, and it's never been deleted.)

If anything, I would have thought my first comment was more likely to be deleted!

(I only have 7k rep, so not sure if a reason for the deletion would be visible if I was over 10k)

Comment: Related:  ["What have you tried" epidemic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic)

Comment: Deleted comments are only visible to moderators.

Comment: _" because it was flagged? "_ Could well be, though I don't see a valid reason why. Only moderators can see deleted comments, that's not for us mean mortals.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  I don't see the value of the comment, even if it's more than a "What have you tried".  Kind of feels like it's imposing an impossible standard of "you should know this before you ask us".

Comment: @Makoto Well, I see ...

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF (and πάντα), makes sense that only mods can see deleted comments and reasons for the deletion.  Shame my entire comment was deleted just because of one keyword, but there you go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments with certain keywords can be removed with just one or very few flags.

Whathaveyoutried.com is such a keyword. Your comment was almost certainly deleted due to someone flagging it as not appropriate.

See ["What have you tried" epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic); your version was a lot more constructive than others that I've seen, however.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it is a trigger keyword @Martijn.  I never use it without more explanation, so it's annoying the entire comment can be deleted simple because of it.  Oh well, live and learn

Answer (score 1):

While [the epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic) certainly has something to do with this, let's look at this a bit closer...

If we remove the "What have you tried" piece, here's what we're left with.

> The problem is that by asking if something is possible, you're effectively saying "please do it for me". Learn about AJAX, how to write it in jQuery, and how to handle it in ASP.NET, and you'll have your solution.

What value is this comment, exactly?

- It points out that the user is just asking for code, which doesn't merit a comment at all - downvotes would suffice here.
- It feels like you're telling the end user to "go learn before asking".  You even at the end remark that they'll have their answer if they learn AJAX, how it's handled in jQuery, and in ASP.NET.  While showing a good-faith research effort is certainly asked of the community, this also feels counter to the goal of the Q&A site.

  It'd be a bit gentler if you asked them to show what work they had done in a way that didn't come across as demeaning.

I would've flagged it myself as "not constructive", because it isn't.  There isn't a redeeming factor about the comment at all.

Comment: OK, I take onboard what you're saying.  But I would disgree that a simple downvote is enough to inform them that they're effectively asking for code

Comment: Read the mouse-over text for a downvote.  It's also a part of the automatic question/answer ban process as well.  If the question isn't useful and it can't be reasonably salvaged, then a downvote is the best thing you could do.

Comment: I have read it, it show three possible reasons (no research effort, unclear, not useful)... therefore which of the three am I picking with my downvote?

Comment: ***Yes.***  There's no real choice between the three with a downvote; if you believe it's either unclear, not useful, *or* there's no research effort, then downvoting is fine.