# Off-topic option: include Unix and Apple sister sites on off-topic notification

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, moderation

Now, for one of the off-topic reasons we have this:

> "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."

But I find Super User is often not the relevant place, especially on how to run our programs on Unix/Linux. This is also not about system administration (another off-topic reason).

So I would complete the actual text with something like:

> "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User **(generic), or specific sites: Unix&Linux, Ask Ubuntu, Ask Different (iOS/macOS)**".

To be clear:

- I was thinking about this for simple closure. I didn't think much about migration
- For me it is mostly Unix&Linux: I find often close notice to SuperUser, where U&L is a much better choice. (Sometimes I am also curious about the answers there). U&L is probably more relevant: deployment of "our" programs. I added Ubuntu and Mac, just because I noticed they are much more popular than U&L.

Comment: While I support the notion, they have not updated the sites in that list in *years*, despite there being a valid need for at least 5 other sites to be added. It's unlikely this'll happen, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is that that flag (or close vote, later on) is supposed to trigger a migration path, AFAIK. I'm not sure how having multiple migration targets would play there.

Comment: @yivi that reason isn't supposed to trigger a migration.

Comment: @Stijn I thought it did. The fact that it appears twice in the close dialog (first tier reasons and within "it belongs to another site") might have confused me.

Comment: But wouldn't the windows users feel left out if there is no migration target for them?

Comment: @user000001 That's not a bug. That's a feature.

Comment: Did you ask on the metas of the sites you're proposing to add whether they are OK with your proposal? Surely that's a rather important first step here.

Comment: @RobertLongson If Stijn is right, picking that choice cannot start a migration process, it would be just an informative message. If that's the case, getting the "approval" of the target sites wouldn't be as necessary, if at all. Right?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You probably want to clarify your question to indicate that you are not suggesting adding migration paths, but rather are just requesting that the text of the close reason that doesn't provoke migration gets modified to include more suggestions. Both of the answers that have been posted have been by people who didn't understand that when they first read it, so it would be beneficial to clarify.

Comment: @yivi but it might drive poor content to those sites so it would seem polite to get their permission first, no?

Comment: Reminds me of [Remove the mention of “Super User” from the standard off-topic close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872)...

Comment: This is technically quite do-able: moderators can change this text. But we need to get approval from the other sites we’re putting in the list, get a consensus from our community, and settle on the actual wording. Needs to be short.

Comment: Frankly, almost all of the off-topic questions I've seen would be garbage on any site, and I don't have any faith in the OP's ability to fix them. Better IMO to just use a generic close reason and manually comment on those few that are actually well-written.

Answer (score 19):

I would rather completely omit the text.  Rather than risk giving an OP false hope about their question which *might* be good, I'd rather be explicit in saying, "No, your question is off-topic *here*," and simply leaving it at that.

I don't disagree with the *sentiment* to offer OPs a place to look, but I don't think questions closed with that reason would even raise to the occasion of migration (and remember - we *can* directly migrate to Super User).

Comment: Yup. This. Do this one. Then, we can get rid of the separate off-topic reasons for Super User and Server Fault, combining them into a single reason and stop me from having to agonize each time over whether, although this is a network-related issue, is it really a *professional network administration* issue? It would also give us another slot to invent a more site-specific closure reason, and I can think of a few ideas for that...

Comment: Rather than suggest a site or list of specific sites, how about: "You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name). However, please be sure to read the on-topic page for the site you select prior to posting."

Comment: @Makyen:  No.  That defeats the purpose.  The point is that the question is off-topic *here*.  Not enough people participate on the other sites to truly be able to gauge topicality or scope.  There's no real benefit to us to bother pointing them to another site if the question they're asking us *here* and *now* is off-topic.  Again, since Super User is a migration path, if the question really were good enough go to on SU, we'd have migrated it instead of voting to close.

Comment: @Makoto I'm a bit confused by your response, as you talk about Super User, which has very little to do with my comment. Did you just assume I linked to [su], but with different text displayed for the link? However, I've realized that discussing this under your answer really isn't the appropriate place. Given that what I've put forward is really an alternate suggestion for the close reason, I'll add an answer which can be voted upon.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than have a single site or a short list of sites in that reason, we could link to the list of [all Stack Exchange technology sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name).

If we do, the close reason could be something like:

> Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow, unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name). Prior to posting on another site, be sure to read that site's on-topic page to determine if your question is on-topic there.

Comment: ...and suddenly 3D Printing comes knocking at our door with machetes because everyone clicked on the first link they saw.

Comment: @CodyGray While some people will click on the first link they see – there's really nothing we can do about that – this seems to be a reasonable balance between being helpful to the question OP by providing them with a link to a list of other sites where their question *might* be on-topic, and being responsible by reiterating that they should read the on-topic page for the site they select. Should we put the "read…on-topic page" in italics? bold? And/or use italics on "*may* be able to get help…"?

Comment: You are taking me a bit too seriously. That comment came with an upvote. I think this strikes a very reasonable balance, and is probably a good idea. I don't think adding emphasis to "may" is helpful; that doesn't clarify anything. Perhaps bolding "be sure to read that site's help center" would be useful. I'm not sure. I actually think the onus for clarifying this should be on the Ask Question page at each individual site.

Comment: @CodyGray Ahh... Sorry. I'm in a bit too serious of a frame of mind at the moment. :-;

Comment: The only real fear that I have with this message is that no one is going to pay attention to the messaging.  The intent is noble but in all reality, the only thing we care about when we close questions is that it's off-topic *here*.  Pointing the OP to somewhere else *really* does feel like we're giving them false hope in that their question *might* be on topic elsewhere.  If at all possible, I'd espouse being terse about the topicality and oblique about other sites that exist.  Figuring out where a question should go is something which shouldn't be that difficult to do.

Comment: *"Figuring out where a question should go is something which shouldn't be that difficult to do."*  This is kind of a security-through-obscurity argument.  It's unfortunately true that off-topic questions usually correlate with other "not paying attention" factors--odds are the question needs work.  But it's cynical to obfuscate that there is a right place to go if they would up their game.  I think that if you guide them not just to the site to repeat their question verbatim...but give them a nudge toward a well vetted "how to ask" for that site...it's the right thing to do.

Comment: @HostileFork:  I'm considering the value of said nudge.  It's been there since time immemorial, yet we still have people who post questions like that which are off-topic *here* in spite of it.  We've had enough angst with people not knowing [if a post is suitable for Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362417/1079354); I say we see both of those scenarios in the same light and simply *not* refer anyone anywhere.  If the question's off-topic here, it's just off-topic here.

Comment: Something like https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-traffic might be a slightly more useful URL to link to.