# Retiring Our Community-Specific Closure Reasons for Server Fault and Super User

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

Thank you to everyone who participated in [Overhauling our community's closure reasons and guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417008/15497888).

It appears that we have quite a few ideas about closure reasons we'd like to add as well as updating the wording for a few of the existing reasons. As mentioned in the previous post, we are currently using **all 5** of our Community Specific Closure Reason slots.

In order to move forward with this process of revising our existing reasons and potentially add a new one, we first need to free up slots. I propose we retire our (2) specific off-topic closure reasons, specifically, Server Fault and Super User in favour of a more general one.

Please review some of the existing proposals:

- [Answer to: Avoiding overly specific site referrals for general computing and sysadmin questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313265)
- [Remove the mention of "Super User" from the standard off-topic close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872)
- [Answer to: Make description of “community-specific reason” close reason more clear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412865) (See Blatantly off-topic)
- [Off-topic option: include Unix and Apple sister sites on off-topic notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380370)
- Overhauling our community's closure reasons and guidance

  - [Cris Luengo's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417659)
  - [Braiam's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417611)
  - [Stephen Ostermiller's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732) (See "Not about programming")

There are more than a few different ideas about what the wording for this reason should be.

Reminder that there are **5 fields** that need to be set for this new combined reason; each have a 500-character limit excluding the first which has a 100-character limit (from [Catjia's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336) answer to [Should we update/clarify our help center with respect to other sites and teams?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362584)):

> 1. **Brief description** (100 characters but should be just a few words) - this is the Bold part of the close reason that appears in the close vote UI when closers are voting to close the post.
> 2. **Usage guidance** - this tells close voters when to use this close reason. It should clarify any edge cases and help voters feel certain they're choosing the correct reason.
> 3. **Post notice close description** - visible to all users. This is a general note about why the question was closed. It can include links to resources that explain the site's policy. It should always start and end with the same thing "This question was closed because it is ... It is not currently accepting answers."
> 4. **Post owner guidance** - this additional information appears in the post notice but only for the asker of the question. It should contain detailed information about how they can improve their post (if possible) and may also include links to help here on meta or in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).
> 5. **Public guidance** - this additional information appears in the post notice for all other users. It is designed to help them know how to guide the asker in improving their question or inform them when the question should be reopened.

(#5 was [changed in May](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356902/please-allow-users-without-the-close-reopen-votes-privilege-to-see-the-full-deta/379011#379011) to be shown to all users, instead of only users with the ["cast close and reopen votes" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).)

You can review our current closure reasons with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1573733).

I would like to ask the community to propose options for *complete* guidance on our new closure reason. Then have the highest scoring answer converted into the new closure reason.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've gone ahead and implemented this change.

The old close reasons specifically mentioning Super User and Server Fault have been deactivated, and this broader "Not about programming or software development" close reason has been added. I used the proposed guidance suggested in [Henry Ecker's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418096/1478931), with some very minor edits. (I'm glad I was able to [help you phrase the usage guidance](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/197438?m=54721436#54721436)!)

I also moved the new close reason to the top of the list of community-specific close reasons, since that's where the previous two were. Hopefully this should ensure minimal disruption to people's workflows... :)

Please let me know if you encounter any technical issues caused by this change (or somehow find any typos in the text).

---

Now that this change has been implemented, y'all may also want to update the [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/1478931) (proposed) guidance to account for these changes in SO's community-specific close reasons.

(The relevant answers: [this one about the "general computing hardware and software" close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417478/1478931) that mentions Super User, and [this one about the "server administration" close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417479/1478931) that mentions Server Fault. Whether y'all repurpose one of those existing answers or just add a new one, you may find it useful to draw on the information in those two answers in crafting the guidance for this new close reason.)

Comment: Freaking finally, why did this take so much time? AFAIK, moderators are be able to do this operation pretty easily, why couldn't them?

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head whether mods can deactivate close reasons; I know they can "add" new close reasons, but a second person needs to approve the reason before it can go live. (I know mods can't edit existing close reasons that are active; editing a close reason also retroactively affects all posts it's currently used on, so CMs rarely do so in the case of any fundamental change to it.) In this case, SO was already at the limit of 5 active close reasons (before this change), so a new close reason couldn't be added without first deactivating the existing reasons.

Comment: "I don't remember off the top of my head whether mods can deactivate close reasons", [they can deactivate them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkHE1.png). What they can't do is modifying them. Also, if they couldn't manage the close reasons, means that they are basically waiting around until a CM push a button? They already can doctor the post history to remove sensitive data, why couldn't they do this that has less stakes?

Comment: @Braiam This [discussion] was created much less that a year ago. Considering the age of many [feature-request]s on this site, why are you so shocked about the fact that this one (again, just a [discussion]) took ~2.5 months? Because it's so "easy" to do? Crikey, give 'em a break.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: In particular, the request was only escalated to the CMs on July 7, which is when a site mod [added the \[status-review\] tag to do so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251).

Comment: @HereticMonkey It seems that you all are missing some ["context"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54937545#54937545). Moderator team decides that instead of solving the problem _now_, since they can, they should wait for a CM. This discussion isn't new for SE, either since, and the question has plenty of examples ready. So, again, which was the blocker for this to take so long, and why CM's didn't tell the moderator team that they should do so themselves? What the heck happened!?

Comment: Is this a case of "trying to be perfect instead of good" kind of behavior? That's unattainable at the size of SO, and if the moderator team and CM's decides to have that as the default policy, we are in a world of trouble. Things need to move faster and the CM's team should encourage the moderator team to use their tooling often, instead of waiting for them.

Comment: At least it happened. We've had these close reasons for years, some logistical delay because employees have to get involved happens, and is negligible in the grand scheme of things. Assume some good faith here. SE has an enormous amount of overhead, and while that's a problem, it's not something we can do anything about, it's not the CM's fault, and it's not worth badgering a CM for when we at least got something we wanted. Take the win and move on to whatever battle is next instead of dying on the hill of "we got it but it was 2 slow and could've been done faster"

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine "negligible in the grand scheme of things" something that has been asked since years ago, and you say it's negligible?? Maybe you need to touch grass and be nearer to the community that you are supposed to serve.

Comment: @Braiam And how exactly is your approach of "CMs are bad for making a positive change because they were too slow by my personal standard" in any way constructive for the community? Things take time and that's unavoidable. The alternative is for CMs to do nothing, would you prefer that? I wouldn't, and I'm solidly of the position that it's better late than never. That said, saying years is a stretch. _This_ proposal gained traction and got completed in a couple months. That's far better than average. We're still waiting for plagiarism tooling, for instance

Comment: But hey, if you feel your time is best spent fighting CMs over a change you wanted and that the CMs came through with rather than focusing on the next thing of significance (whatever that may be for you), be my guest.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I want to understand what happened so it doesn't happen again with the change I want. For me the objective and the process to achieve it is equally important. Also, this is not the change I want. What I wanted is better.

Comment: This was a substantial enough change to the existing close reasons that it didn't make sense to retroactively overwrite all posts closed with either of those reasons with this text. At the mods' request, I did partly edit those close reasons to no longer directly recommend asking on SU/SF, but I don't think it would have made sense here to totally replace the previous wording with this wording on all posts previously closed with those two close reasons.

Answer (score 106):

Personally, as much as I appreciate the idea of giving as detailed feedback as possible, I think giving lists of options is not the correct approach as:

- any list will eventually go out of date as new sites are added (or removed) from the network
- we are limited to 500-characters and standard(ish) Markdown rules

For this reason, I'd prefer to have a general "not about programming or development" closure reason, and provide the general list of sites rather than trying to enumerate every possible location for every type of question. I've instead chosen to link to [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which already covers where to ask many types of questions. This practice is also consistent with our existing closure reasons and the closure reasons of many other communities network wide.

This is my proposal:

| Field | (Rendered) Markdown | Markdown Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brief Description | Not about programming or software development | 45 |
| Usage guidance | Use this close reason if the question is not about [a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers](/help/on-topic). Do not use this close reason for questions that are on-topic for $SiteName, even if it would also be on-topic on [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Questions *about* $SiteName itself should be migrated to [Meta $SiteName](/help/whats-meta) instead. | 449 |
| Post notice close description | **Closed.** This question is [not about programming or software development](/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers. | 140 |
| Post owner guidance | This question does not appear to be about [a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers](/help/on-topic). You can edit the question so it’s [on-topic](/help/on-topic) or see if it can be answered on [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites), but be sure to read the on-topic page for the site you choose before posting. | 397 |
| Public user guidance | This question does not appear to be about [a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers](/help/on-topic). If you believe the question is on-topic on [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) you can leave a comment to explain where the question may be able to be answered. | 350 |

---

As I was working on this, I realised it was difficult for me to conceptualise what these reasons would feel like in situ, so I have created a mock closure dialogue and some mock close banners.

The close dialogue would look something like:
[image: Close Dialogue with new closure reasons and no SF or SU close reasons]

Post Owners would see the following message:
[image: Post owner guidance]

Privileged Users would see the following:
[image: Privileged user guidance]

Anonymous Users and users with less than 3000 reputation would see the following:
[image: Every user guidance]

---

This should be able to support the prior closure reasons as it represents the essence of why "general computing hardware and software" and "professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration" are off-topic.

It should also cover many of the custom close reasons currently being used. For Example:

| Category | Approx # of Variants<sup>1</sup> | Approx # of posts (last 30 days)<sup>1</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ML/DL/AI theory and/or methodology | ~8 | ~230 |
| Not about Programming as defined in [help] | ~34 | ~206 |
| Webmasters | ~4 | ~47 |
| Mathematics | ~1 | ~3 |
| DataScience | ~1 | ~3 |

<sup>1</sup> Values were aggregated with the highly accurate and extremely technical method of "by hand" from [question close stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last30days). Custom closure reasons are considered distinct unless they match spelling and punctuation *exactly* so finding all variants and their associated amounts is non-trivial.

---

I would like to acknowledge that these reasons are the derived from many users network wide. My hope was to create reasons with guidance and links that were consistent with our existing reasons, help center, and MSO. I also pulled the current community-specific closure reasons for every community on the Stack Exchange network to see how they handle off-topic questions on their relative sites. My hope is not that this guidance is revolutionary or groundbreaking, but rather something that is familiar and can be easily adopted by our community.

A special thanks to [Oleg Valter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11407695) and [Ryan M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208273) for their assistance in getting this proposal into somewhat reasonable form, as well as everyone who participated in the initial [close reasons and guidance project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417475/15497888) and in the [Overhauling our community's closure reasons and guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417008/15497888) discussion.

Comment: I have some problems with the "commonly used by programmers", the old "primarily used by programmers" better covers it, because otherwise you get into those nice arguments like "as a developer, I commonly use a computer, so all computer questions are on-topic".

Comment: When did the help center change to commonly instead of primarily @MarkRotteveel ? I missed the memo,

Comment: @Braiam I don't know when it changed

Comment: "Not about programming or software development". What's the difference? Those two terms are synonymous, far as I know.

Comment: It wasn't a problem before if you consider [that it's the combination of two statement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357485/is-it-tools-used-commonly-by-programmers-or-primarily-for-programming#comment520048_357485)

Comment: One word isn't going to make a difference.  We did this sort of word splitting for ages on Software Engineering; the only place where wording made a material difference in the quality of the questions asked was when the site changed its name from Programmers to Software Engineering.

Comment: A minor quibble, but I would limit the SE list to [just technology sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology). Unless you think Interpersonal Skills would be helpful in diagnosing if my HDD is dead

Comment: @Machavity limiting to just technology would exclude: Cross Validated, Mathematics, Computer Science, Artificial Intelligence, Theoretical Computer Science ([Science](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-traffic)) which we get a fair amount of questions for so much so that we have a migration path for Cross Validated. It would also exclude Law ([Life & Arts](https://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts-traffic)) and Open Source ([Professional](https://stackexchange.com/sites#professional-traffic)) which while less common are also potential site targets.

Comment: @HenryEcker Fair enough, but that raises a much larger issue. So, I've just asked my dead HDD question on SO and gotten closed. I'm plucky so I click into the list. How do I pick a better site to ask about it on? That list is full of vague names ("Super User" is clever but does not describe that the site is about hardware/OS questions). FWIW, the SU closure reason (flawed as it is) at least suggests where to start.

Comment: I certainly agree with that @Machavity The [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page is a much more informative than just the sites list. I was trying to limit the number of incorrect referrals, but I agree that this certainly provides much less direct feedback about where to ask. I don't know what would be better: too narrow that it excludes viable options or too broad that it's hard to determine where to post. Some sites link to specific meta posts. I couldn't find a canonical "Where to ask off-topic questions instead of Stack Overflow" on MSO as I did on some other sites.

Comment: @Machavity I think that just like for questions on site's we don't have a custom close reason now for the asker will just have to hope someone (correctly) comments "your question may be on topic at Foo.SE".

Comment: I did also try to encourage comments by including "If you believe the question is on-topic on another site on the Stack Exchange Network you can leave a comment to explain where the question may be able to be answered." in the privileged user guidance... though how effective that will be or not can't really be measured in advance. I think the core issue is more that there is not a good singular reference to direct people to which will help them pick what site to ask on.

Comment: IMHO, really need to include that all-important **"... and unique to software development"** qualifier.  Lots of tools are commonly used by programmers, but as @Braiam mentioned, it's the combination of those two statements that determines whether it is on-topic.

Comment: May I suggest linking to [the FAQ on meta for which site to choose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/566903) instead of some flavor of https://stackexchange.com/sites?

Comment: That's exactly the kind of resource I was looking for @pppery ! Thank you for the link. While that post provides much better guidance than just the all sites list it does not have information about Super User or Server Fault which is a bit of an issue given how many of those types of questions Stack Overflow gets... if it were possible to include those in that answer that would be great. Alternatively a dedicated MSO post to link to may also be a good option.

Comment: It's a community wiki post -- feel free to edit it to add anything you feel is missing.

Comment: @Lundin 'software development' includes things like agile/scrum questions, which 'programming' does not (just as one example)

Comment: @TylerH that's why the "unique" is also there :)

Comment: @Braiam The word "unique" is not in the phrase Lundin asked about.

Comment: @TylerH Which is why [I used it on my proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417611/792066), instead of what Henry has.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure why you are responding here about it then since the comments here are an entirely different conversation.

Comment: @TylerH if Henry had instead copied the text I proposed, Lundin will not have commented, so yeah, same conversation.

Comment: *"Not a practical, answerable problem unique to software development"* What purpose does "unique" serve here?

Comment: i mean, the whole point of this project was to  refine the close reasons/guidance and pass that on to the help center wasn't it?

Comment: @Braiam Henry did not copy the text you proposed. Henry wrote their own answer under a different question and Lundin responded to that one. It really doesn't make sense to respond as if the comments and post above include content that they don't actually include.

Comment: @TylerH I did add in the unique piece for a revision (copied from the help centre not not any of Braiam's posts/comments) for a bit, but I've reverted that as I somewhat missed the forest through the trees and made a change that I disagreed with rather than allowing others to submit their own answers which was my mistake.

Comment: For what it's worth, @MarkRotteveel, I checked, and the https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic page has said "software tools commonly used by programmers" since the very first tracked revision, from June 3, 2013. This is not something that has changed recently.

Comment: It appears that the this "primarily for programming" comes from the closure reasons dialogue [at least at some point in 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357485/15497888) even if it did not ever appear in help/on-topic @CodyGray

Comment: Good thing I went spelunking the other day and found this quote "It does but as the other two answers pointed out, using the tag emacs is not a magic wand that makes every question on topic, either" — [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79660/213575) when talking about the "commonly used by programmers" bit.

Comment: @TylerH No that would be project management and also explicitly off-topic, see the agile tag description.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of what you would call "software development" it's senseless to have something phrased as "not about programming and not about programming+extra stuff". "Not about software development" would suffice.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, I wasn't aware (or had forgotten) that this confusion is older.

Comment: @Lundin We can change the tag wiki at will; the description doesn't affect whether the tag's topic itself is on-topic here or not.

Comment: @TylerH In this case the tag description is fine, since such questions do not belong here. There's https://pm.stackexchange.com/ for that.

Comment: @Lundin Sure, and I agree. But we aren't talking about whether it's on-topic here or not; we're talking about what the difference is between programming and software development, which is what you asked.

Comment: @TylerH So you think the close reason should be called "Not about programming or project management"?

Comment: @KevinB I would add modifying the help center too to bring it in line with guidance/close reasons. Basically, that everything agrees.

Comment: @Lundin No I am saying agile and scrum etc. are aspects that fit under the umbrella of 'software development' but not under the umbrella of 'programming'.

Comment: I like this because it means I don't need a custom close reason to close questions that are completely unrelated to the site in any conceivable way (and yes, we do get those sometimes, and they aren't just attempts at dropping spam on the site). I think the wording should be tweaked, though, so that it can also pick up all the "how do I become a better programmer?" / "I have been trying this for X months and am just generally confused; is that normal?" etc. type questions that belong on a discussion forum.

Comment: I think those types of questions should be closed as "primarily opinion-based", @Karl, not as [the equivalent of] "blatantly off-topic". *Ideally*, close reasons will be as descriptive as possible to give actionable and educational advice.

Comment: I suggest changing "software tools" to "software tool" in all three instances.  "Software algorithm" and "programming problem" are both singular, so including a plural for the third item makes it flow badly.  I realized that you probably chose this wording to exactly mirror the help center, but the help center could probably use the same update.  It bothers me more when used in a single sentence like this than when used in a bulleted list in the help center.

Comment: Should the post owner guidance have an admonition against cross-posting on **multiple** other sites?  I worry that directing users to a big list of other sites where they can ask is going to prompt some people to post on several of them at once.

Comment: I think there have been more than a few concerns about linking to /sites. I think the current proposal is to replace it with a link to a MSO faq which can outline everything and give more useful guidance than just a list of sites with minimal explanation. Though nothing has been started (as far as I am aware) to make that a reality. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: The "usage guidance" isn't usage guidance. This text should be clear instructions to readers regarding when to use the close reason - and when to not use it. Right now you're just creating a long-form version of the close reason name. Please use the guidance in the question for how to frame these. If there are any occasions when this close reason shouldn't be used, please mention them, too.

Comment: Additionally, the "privileged user guidance" (which is technically now visible by everyone) should indicate how a reader can improve the question (e.g. "If you can improve the question such that it is on topic here, consider editing it.") You do this in the question owner section but not in the privileged user section.

Comment: @Catija Will do on the usage guidance section. You are correct it does not really provide information on how to use the reason and can be reworded to be more clear.

Comment: WRT the privileged user guidance section, it was felt in the initial drafts that most questions closed with this reason cannot be improved by other users than the author. If there is a programmatic aspect to a networking administration question, but this is not contained in the question already, an edit to make an off-topic question about programming would conflict with our current editing guidelines (as an example). For this reason editing was not included in the privileged guidance, and instead it encourages users to comment to help the author figure out where to ask instead.

Comment: I am very much open to feedback on this point, however, if that early decision was incorrect.

Comment: @HenryEcker That's fine - y'all are the experts here. I completely understand that some close reasons are used on questions that are generally never going to be in scope. Feel free to ping me if you want help with the usage guidance. :)

Answer (score -7):

This is my proposal which is exactly the same as Henry except that it is less ambiguous, more sober and more dry cut, trying to do less things at once:

| Field | (Rendered) Markdown | Markdown Length* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brief Description | Not a practical, answerable problem unique to software development | 66 |
| Usage guidance | This question does not appear to be about [a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers in a context unique to software development](/help/on-topic). | 270 |
| Post notice close description | **Closed.** This question is [not a practical, answerable problem unique to software development](/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers. | 161 |
| Post owner guidance | This question does not appear to be about [a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers in a context unique to software development](/help/on-topic). You can edit the question so it’s [on-topic](/help/on-topic). | 270 |
| Privileged user guidance | This question does not appear to be about [a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarly used by programmers in a context unique to software development](/help/on-topic). | 206 |

Comment: Actually, yes, the removal of the "may be on topic..." parts have been workshoped yesterday and looked upon favourably. Henry? Not sure about the "context", though. Can you give an example of a tool used by programmers not in the prpgrammkng context?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Computers? Drills? Coffee makers?

Comment: I think Oleg's question is about "software tools" (as written) not used in a programming context @Braiam

Comment: I object to any of those being "tools primarily used by programmers", @Braiam :) Unless that's a joke, that is.

Comment: @HenryEcker Word? <insert here favorite web browser>? Windows? Linux?

Comment: And same for the list of software below - unless, again, this is a joke, I do not see how OS or browser is a "tool primarily used by programmers" (in fact, where have you seen a programmer using MS Word??).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine sadly, now programmers believe that anything they use is "primarily" used by them. So, lets make sure that it's actually when they are actively programming and those are commonly used by them. It's the same double conditional that we use when we say that you can ask an on-topic but unclear question. Now the topic is restricted by two conditions.

Comment: *"less ambiguous, more sober and more dry cut"* err... it's more ambiguous isn't it? it appears to be more verbose, because it has more words, but the words added don't make determining which tools are relevant and which ones aren't any easier.

Comment: Still waiting on an example of usage of a tool *primarily* used by programmers in a non-programming context, though, @Braiam :)

Comment: @KevinB "in a context unique to software development"? Are you sure? It removes generic Word, Excel, Chrome questions while still allowing VBA's, JS/HTML/CSS questions.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine And I told you that I don know what such a tool looks anymore! Programmers will claim that anything they use is "primarily" used by them. Instead of trying to leave them to apply their own concept, I close the barn door immediately by telling them that it should be used in the context of programming.

Comment: @Braiam there *are* questions for each of those tools that are on topic here.

Comment: While I am aware that the /allsites list is overly broad, and I acknowledge I have not yet found a better option. I strongly disagree with _only_ telling the post author to edit their question. Most of the questions closed with this reason will probably not be abled to be salvaged through editing.

Comment: @HenryEcker and that's ok, for us. We don't have any obligation to tell the asker where they can ask their question. I prefer telling them in a cut and dry way that their post doesn't meet our standard, instead of diluting the message trying to be helpful. Remember, this message will apply to every question, from cooking, to gaming, to agile, etc. Any list will be by default incomplete.

Comment: @KevinB yes! When they are "in a context unique to software development". That's why that is in there.

Comment: @Braiam is some form of punctuation missing? *"software tools primarily used by programmers in a context unique to software development"*, to me reads as tools primarily used by programmers for things that are unique to software development. aka something used for a multitude of things, like excel, wouldn't be unique to software development. I can assume, given past interactions on meta, what you meant, but I'd prefer close reasons that don't require that kind of assumption.

Comment: "*my proposal which is exactly the same as Henry except that it is less ambiguous, more sober and more dry cut*" So, it is not "exactly the same", then, is it?

Comment: @TylerH well, it also has a table!

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine *"Can you give an example of a tool used by programmers not in the prpgrammkng context?"*   [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux] questions *very often* are not programming related.  WSL is commonly used by programmers, but not exclusively, and questions about WSL networking, configuring colors, and many others are not on-topic.  The same could be said for most any shell (PowerShell, Bash, etc.) -- There are script related (and other) questions that would be on-topic, but general usage questions would not be.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I often put in a close-comment that says something like: "Keep in mind that questions on Stack Overflow should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems" (i.e. "unique to software development")*.  Non-programming WSL questions are usually better suited for one of the sister sites here such as [Super User](https://superuser.com), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com), or (if the question is Ubuntu-specific) [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). This one looks like a good target for Super User." (etc.)

Comment: @Braiam's proposed close text would go a long way towards explaining that on its own.

Comment: What do people actually object to in this proposal, to merit the downvotes?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Downvotes on the meta site often mean that people like another post better.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel adding more reasons to StephenOstermiller comment: that while others answers are meh, this one is one I don't like. Or Tim lost it's keys. Or that it is already downvoted. Really, who knows.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I understand that, but I would *really like to hear the reasoning* of those people! Even knowing that they aren't obligated, I'm extending the invitation.