# What resource should we direct users to when closing their question as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Over the past week or so, I have been working on addressing the concerns that were raised about the proposed new closure reason [Not about programming or software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418096/15497888).

Almost every issue has been addressed or discussed; however, there is one more piece which is still being debated and requires additional input. There are some concerns about the follow up guidance resource after closure.

The current version links to https://stackexchange.com/sites and there are mixed feeling about this as the resource.

### /sites: the pros and cons

There are those who feel that this is not an adequate resource to direct users to. That this page does not adequately *help* someone figure out what site they should post their question on. Additionally it doesn't explain anything about the rules of cross posting or any other reposting guidelines.

On the other hand, this is a complete reference of *every* site that is available on the network. It requires no manual updating by this community as new sites are added. Additionally, this resource is complete and would not require *this community* to have and maintain detailed knowledge of what is on or off topic on the various sites across the network.

### A Meta FAQ: the pros and cons

The MSE FAQ [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/1099857) was [proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/910121) as an alternative. However, in line with the concern above about requiring manual updates as new sites are added, that post does not include *many* important sites, namely Super User and Server Fault which are being replaced by this new reason.

I don't personally feel that I have a strong enough understanding of what is on-topic on either of those sites to make the updates to that post myself. Additionally that post includes Stack Overflow which is not necessary for our purposes.

It has also been proposed that we create a new MSO FAQ which can be tailored to referrals away from Stack Overflow, however, again this would be something the community would need to actively create and then maintain.

On the other hand, a meta post would be very easy to make changes when they were needed and we could determine as a community exactly how we wanted to handle off-site referrals. But again, because it would require on-going upkeep, I don't want to move forward with this path without some confirmation this is what the community wants.

---

Some other things to note:

- The current public and private banner also links to our [on-topic page](/help/on-topic) which does provide some specific referrals (site icons were removed because they were oversized without CSS).

> **If your question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow**, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). If your question would be of interest to…
>
> - Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
> - Professional system and network administrators, ask on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
> - Operating and managing your own website, including questions about SEO, domain names, and web/email hosting, ask on
>   [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)
> - Users of Apple hardware, software, services, and associated products, ask on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)
> - Users of Linux, FreeBSD, and other Un*x-like operating systems, ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
> - Users of TeX, LaTeX, and related typesetting systems, ask on [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)
> - Database administrators and professionals, ask on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)
> - Statisticians, data analysts, and data miners, ask on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)
> - SharePoint enthusiasts, ask on [SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

- The public usage guidance encourages commenting to let the user know where they can ask instead. This is *already* an extremely common practice when closing new questions as off topic. My hope initially is that this is where the most meaningful referrals would come from.

---

So the questions are:

- where should we direct users when closing their question as off topic?
- Do we keep the current resource links as they are /help/on-topic + /sites, or do we build a new FAQ?
- Is there a better option than either of the two currently proposed?

Comment: "however, again this would be something the community would need to actively create and then maintain." Using this sort of thing as a reason not to do things, is a big part of how Stack Overflow got into this mess in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what "this mess" you're referring to is specifically here. I also didn't say we _shouldn't_ do this for that reason. I said "I don't want to move forward with this path without some confirmation this is what the community wants." Personally, I dislike it _more_ when someone moves forward with a plan that's going to make more work for _me_ later without getting my input beforehand.

Comment: Isn't the entire point of the change that we *don't* want to direct people to specific other sites or resources? Just because we can say for sure that a question does not fit here does not mean that we can say, guess or even just suggest where else it would fit.

Answer (score 16):

> where should we direct users when closing their question as off topic?

IMO, the on-topic page. If that does not contain enough information, it should be enhanced. Anything else is a workaround, and we have those help center pages for a reason.

It is 100% wrong to (only) link people to the sites page. That's essentially just telling people to Google it in different words. "Here is a giant list, go figure it out yourself". No, people who visit Stack Overflow tend to fall into a narrower subset of sites, and we can help them find their way. And to me, the on-topic page does exactly that. The on-topic page itself contains a link to the full list, so nothing is lost.

I'm on the fence about the length of the on-topic page though. It is tall enough to have the wall-of-text syndrome. Help center pages can do with a table of contents of sorts, so right at the top you'd have a link which points you directly to "List of sites for other types of questions", or something along those lines. Coming up with descriptive labels is a skill on its own...

Comment: The advantage of a community answer in meta, as proposed by @HenryEcker, is that it can be enhanced by the community, while the help pages cannot.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε that can also act as a disadvantage. Some things should not be so easy to change on a whim by individuals (people keep saying "the community", but individuals do the work on their own accord). From what I've learned moderators can edit help center pages, that sounds like exactly the right trajectory for me. Meta post discussion -> concensus -> moderator makes it so.

Comment: The on-topic page can't possibly list all the alternative places where you can ask a question.  That isn't, and shouldn't be its job.  The on-topic page should describe what **can** actually be asked here.

Answer (score 0):

We should ask a new question on Stack Overflow meta:

> ### Which other Stack Exchange site might be appropriate for my closed question?
>
> This question is linked from questions closed as [Not about programming or software development.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418096/15497888) and its purpose is to provide a list of other Stack Exchange sites that might be appropriate for such closed questions.

It should have a single answer that lists other sites where questions from Stack Overflow usually would be better asked. This new answer should be a community-wiki answer so that it is editable.

If we find that inappropriate edits get made to this answer, the moderators have the option of locking it which effectively would make it moderator-editable only.

---

I don't like the idea the close reason linking directly to https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday because that page is not well sorted for relevance to Stack Overflow.  https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday might be slightly better, but even it has the various language sites listed on it prominently, which makes it hard to use.

---

I don't like the idea of putting this list in the help center.

- The help center can never be community editable
- It is not possible to create new pages in the help center
- Putting this list in the on-topic help center page would detract from the important information that is there and make the page too long.