# How come Server Fault is no longer a migration destination?

Tags: discussion, custom-close-reasons

The current options are Meta, [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour), [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour), and [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour). Many times I want to refer a question to Server Fault, but it is no longer an option. Why are *TeX - LaTeX* and Meta in the list but the more useful Server Fault is not?

Comment: See: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3853/should-server-fault-be-removed-from-stack-overflows-migration-list

Comment: From my personal experience, I would suggest [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and [data science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) as popular migration destinations too. Maybe a search box for us to search and choose from other stackexchange sites would be good...?

Comment: I see the point of that meta SF discussion, but SO feels like L1 tech support in charged of routing questions to the correct SE community.

Comment: @drum No need to route posts to the correct site, just close them for being off-topic. Unless you're aware about exactly what post would be suitable for a site it's best not to go for migration.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Which begs the question: why have the migration list at all?

Comment: @drum I guess at this point the main purpose is to remind people there are actually other sites.

Comment: @ray **definitely not** Code Review. This gets suggested constantly by people who are unaware of the problems it has caused in the past. The Code Review site has **very particular** standards for question posts that are extremely unlikely to be met "naturally" by someone who posts code on Stack Overflow and wants general feedback.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel SO shouldn't be responsible for CR's problems. SO has **very particular** standards for its questions, too.

Comment: @TylerH Indeed. But SO should also not dump questions on CR if they don't satisfy CR's requirements.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The migration process already has systems in place to handle that. Mods can consult other site mods for ones that are requested via mod flag, and any that are not suitable for the target site are rejected if the target site closes them.

Comment: @TylerH It seems you don't understand the effect that a large site migrating questions to a small site has on the smaller site. There is close to 100% chance that a question posted on SO will be closed after migration to CR, which means migration just adds work to the community there. And once closed, the user doesn't get the chance to update their question to match the CR requirements. It's best for people to post a new question on CR, after becoming familiar with the site. So just point them there, rather than try to get the question migrated.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I do understand the effect. I just don't think it's actually a problem. But if there's a shortcoming in the migration process, that should ideally be addressed by making a feature request to improve the tool (like migration putting the question in draft state and making the user read the tour on the target site, first), rather than just saying "don't use the tool".

Comment: I think the migration list should be reworked to not migrate and instead post a comment similar to "duplicates" pointing them to the other SE sites. It's more of a shortcut so the person flagging doesn't have to do so as much manual work.

Comment: @TylerH Look at it from the other direction - what's the *benefit* of allowing migration to Code Review if it's only going to be misused? Even if you don't think it's a big deal, a minor problem is still worse than no problem.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Who said it's only going to be misused? That's not "looking at it from the other direction", that's "assuming an entirely different scenario".

Comment: @TylerH The comment you replied to said that. You claimed you understood.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery No, the comment said "close to 100% chance the question will be closed after migration" which is speculative, not backed up, and not the same as 100%, nor does it mean "misused". It seems you are the one who did not understand it.

Comment: @TylerH how about this argument then. Code Review say they [don't want to be a migration target from Stack Overflow](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-questions-are-suitable-for-migration-to-code-review-and-how-does-the-proce/1688#1688). Should we ignore them? That doesn't seem very polite.

Answer (score 12):

You either have a very good memory of how [migration was set up over a decade ago](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/3885/356904), or are actually thinking of the change in [Retiring Our Community-Specific Closure Reasons for Server Fault and Super User](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418095/6083675):

> It appears that we have quite a few ideas about closure reasons we'd like to add as well as updating the wording for a few of the existing reasons. As mentioned in the previous post, we are currently using all 5 of our Community Specific Closure Reason slots.
>
> In order to move forward with this process of revising our existing reasons and potentially add a new one, we first need to free up slots. I propose we retire our (2) specific off-topic closure reasons, specifically, Server Fault and Super User in favour of a more general one.

Comment: Actually the former one :)

Comment: I remember it. I used it rarely enough that I got confused where it went _last year_.