# Close reason "This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem" listed twice

Tags: bug, close-reasons, closed-questions

For some reason (maybe because they used to be two different close reasons but were edited), [nginx case insensitive URL redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21577841/6083675) has a duplicated close reason:

[image: two bullets]

> - This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers. If you believe the question would be on-topic on another Stack Exchange site, you can leave a comment to explain where the question may be able to be answered.
> - This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers. If you believe the question would be on-topic on another Stack Exchange site, you can leave a comment to explain where the question may be able to be answered.

It should not have two identical messages. This wasn't a duplicate closure, after all.

Comment: Why not? People come to meta asking why their questions were closed, when it's written right above their questions. So best spam their question with the close message.

Comment: I'm resisting the urge to report this a second time.

Comment: @AndreasmovedtoCodidact if they can't be bothered to read the first time, why would they read the second? You can put a gun to the head of some folks, and they STILL wouldn't read the <expletive deleted>ing manual.

Comment: @user4581301 Let’s test that assumption, in good SE spirit; for every closed question, send a ChatGPT robot to the home address of the asker. Now pray that ChatGPT will be accurate and not hallucinate.

Comment: A hallucinating Chat GPT robot with a gun... I think that would be [something like this](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093870/characters/nm0205727)

Answer (score 13):

The short answer is that you are correct that "they used to be two different close reasons but were edited"

If we look at [an archived version of the page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170215172553/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577841/nginx-case-insensitive-url-redirection) you can see that it was closed under a split 2-3 vote. Two votes for Server Fault and 3 for Super User:

[image]

---

A big part of the rationale behind [retiring the Super User and Server Fault closure reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418095) was because there were (and are) many off-topic questions that fall somewhere in between or totally outside the scope of either of those two sites. So we created a more general off-topic reason which allowed users to close off-topic Stack Overflow questions without needing to pick somewhere else where it would/could be on-topic. This is especially helpful in an age where the network is much larger than just the trio of sites.

As part of the process for adding the new reason, it was decided that the old closure reasons for Super User and Server Fault would be edited so that the banners matched the new "Not about programming" reason.  [V2Blast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419597), a former Community Manager, handled updating the old text, deactivating the old reasons, and enabling the new closure reason.

Rolling the changes out like this was basically a way to automatically "update" all of the old Super User/Server Fault closure banners to reflect the newer, more general closure text without having to reopen/reclose a large number of questions.

At scale, this was determined to be the most effective way to make this change. However, we do end up with a small number of edge cases like the one shown here. Unfortunately, the only (viable) way to fix this would be to reopen and reclose each individual question that was impacted by this change.