# Make tags that have associated Stack Exchange sites more obvious

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I do salesforce development and was curious how many people ask [salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/salesforce) questions in the regular Stack Overflow community. Salesforce has released some new frontend tools so I thought there would be some questions, and sure enough I saw a few.

That got me wondering if there's anything on the tag that links to a more appropriate community, and there is in the description of the tag https://stackoverflow.com/tags/salesforce/info

The problem is, this isn't that obvious and you have to click into the tag to see. It would be awesome if there was a way to make this more obvious when asking questions so people are asking in an area that will reach a bigger audience.

Perhaps color coding a tag will signify the tag has a dedicated community and the author is posting the question in a different community than the dedicated community?

Comment: *[shuffles through my bag of questions]* You mean like this? [Be proud of tag wikis!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279450/be-proud-of-tag-wikis) (MSE)

Comment: @Will sure, but I guess I'm advocating this information shouldn't just live in the wiki. Which I guess I could live with it living in the wiki, but I wish it was more obvious. So yeah, redesign the tags lol

Comment: Quite a few tags like these - [macos] (Ask Different), [raspberry-pi] (Raspberry Pi), [windows] (Super User).

Comment: Just FYI, this won't work for [tag:android] tag because [android.se] doesn't accept app development question and will advise the poster back to [so].

Comment: @Will the wikis vary WILDLY in quality and usecases covered. for eg the scala one has a tutorial on scala concepts using stackoverflow resources while the python one just links to external resources. I know it's a wiki but maybe there should be more of a structured template for it to be considered useful. as it is it reminds me of reddit wikis that mods use to keep track of info for the dedicated elements of the community but more casual users never look at- and are similarly hidden away and hard to access.

Comment: Maybe the [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/4221706) could give a hint about the existence of a specialized site and add some guidance about what is on-topic on SO and on the other networks site.

Comment: @AndrewT. That's probably easily managed by the company when they implement such a thing. It's rare enough that it would probably best be a list that's curated manually on an ad-hoc basis.

Comment: And how about a callout to the site in the sidebar when you're *viewing* questions? It would fit in well with the Linked, Related, and Hot Network Questions sections.

Answer (score 8):

What bout adding a little stack exchange logo to tags that have dedicated sites around the network? (Apologies for my paint skills, hopefully gets the idea across)

[image]

Comment: Many tags have associated logos so that alone wouldn't hint that there's something unusual about this tag.

Comment: Indeed, associated logos. If a tag has an exchange logo, it indicates it’s “associated” with the exchange network. I agree at first glance it might not be obvious though.

Answer (score 7):

For a few tags, SE implemented pop-up messages that show when inserting the tag into a new question.

Such messages could be used for these tags with a message e.g. along these lines:

> "We have a [specialized site](https://foo.stackexchange.com) about Foo where you may get
>   better help than on a general site like Stack Overflow. [Switch to
>   foo.stackexchange.com](https://foo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)."

Comment: That's cool. Do you know of an example that I could see this working for?

Comment: @Programmatic [tag:vba]

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that this is a good idea for the simple fact that this would effectively be [commentating to redirect a user to another Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362417/1079354), just enforced by the UI.

If a question is *also* on-topic here, there's no reason - at all - to discourage a user from asking about it here.  Sending them elsewhere with a UI cue only adds more burden to the process of a user trying to get their otherwise on-topic question answered.

If a question *isn't* on-topic here but *is* on that specialty site, *then* and ***only* then** should we direct their attention elsewhere.

Comment: It wouldn't be discouraging at all to post it here. It would act as a suggestion for the user. It would then be up to the user to decide which site is more appropriate, or maybe both. Its purpose is to inform the user there might be a better place, not an enforcement.

Comment: @Programmatic:  My philosophy is simpler.  If you present a user in a hurry with two options, their ability to make informed and well-guided decisions is dramatically diminished.  Best case scenario is that they'll find it themselves through the guidance we provide **on the question they post here** - be that either a mod migration, migration by the community (rare), or through question closure.  Worst case (and most common) scenario is that they decide to post it on both sites because they were unclear on the guidance they received.

Comment: I'm not understanding why it's bad they post the same question across multiple sites. That would be better than them asking it here and getting 0 responses, which is the case for most [Salesforce] tagged questions.

Comment: @Makoto I would say that if a user is in a hurry, Stack Overflow is probably the wrong place to post a question, as the question is likely to be of poor quality (not researched, no duplicate search, no care taken for ensuring a good MCVE [if required], etc.). I'm not sure that this proposal is warranted, but advertising the existence of other sites spreads the pain -- I mean love -- around.