# Failed audit for suggesting a post on Code Review

Tags: discussion

I just [failed my first review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/23563681) for suggesting a user may get better answers on Code Review.

The question presents two options of working code, and asks:

> What are the pros and cons? Or is there a third option?

To me, this question would attract opinionated answers. I suggested in a comment that they may get better quality answers on Code Review. I **did not** suggest that the question was off-topic for Stack Overflow. This led to a failed review.

Is this the desired result? How can I avoid future failed reviews while continuing to try to help new users?

---

**Edit**: The marked duplicate [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers) outlines criteria that should be followed before recommending that a question be posted on code review. This question passes all of these criteria:

- Real code has to be written.
- The code has to work.
- Broken code or troubleshoot bugs is off-topic.
- Requests to explain others' code are off-topic.

This suggests that I correctly suggested that the question be posted on Code Review (I agree). Nominating that this question be reopened on this basis.

Comment: It's simple: [**don't post comments saying that this would be good for Code Review**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362417/1079354).  Like, at all.

Comment: Given the high, positive score this post had, I'm guessing it didn't have any down votes before you reviewed it. So while your first problem is that commenting causes the audit to fail, your other problem is that a question asking "which way is better" was deemed an unambiguously good question by the community. You got unlucky. (In my experience the voting on questions asking for comparisons or pro/con lists varies wildly. You may want to just be very careful of posts like that.)

Comment: @gnat — following this checklist, the question should be recommended for Code Review. It's real, working code, and not someone else's. With no bugs or troubleshooting required.

Comment: @BSMP Looking at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56939886/timeline), it had two downvotes as of July 8. Still more positive than it should have been, but I'm surprised it was chosen as an audit target.

Comment: A question is not off-topic because it fits on code review. Unless you think it's too broad or should be closed for another reason, just leave it be. Else, vote/flag to close and possibly add a comment. Questions that fit on both are best left on the site they were posted on, even though they might fit better on another site.

Comment: @ErikA At no point did I suggest it was off-topic for StackOverflow. My question states that in bold.

Comment: I didn't say you did, my point is, if it's not off topic here, never recommend other sites, since we want to leave it here

Comment: @Sean. IMHO that Q is _not_ a good candidate for CR.  That checklist are not the only requirements for a CR Q, including: 1) On CR any and every aspect  of the code is up for review, the OP only asks about one aspect.  2) the code must be complete working code (the OP isn't, as witnessed by the `....` towards the bottom of the code block).