# Should I flag a mod-flag if a user advises (repeatedly) that askers take questions to other sites of the network, erroneously?

Tags: discussion, comments, vote-to-close, custom-flags, network-sites

I've encountered a user (by virtue of seeing their comments in questions on the close-review queue) that with some consistency votes to close many questions with a custom reason reading something like:

> I'm voting to close this question because it's about [foo] and should be asked instead on [[foo].stackexchange.com](https://example.com)

Sometimes the comment comes after the VTC, not necessarily  with the custom close-vote.

The problems are:

- [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) is not off-topic here, there are plenty of on-topic questions about [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) on the site.
- Many times (probably in every occasion) the question is off-topic here for a different reason than being about [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) and *wouldn't be really on-topic* on [[foo].stackexchange.com](https://example.com) either.

  E.g. the questions are woefully incomplete, blatant library recommendations, completely opinion based, or the like. And if the questions didn't have those issues... they could be on-topic here on SO as well.

This user has been approached more than once, including by yours truly, about stopping this practice, but they haven't. I've seen this kind of comment about different sites in the network, although I'm not equally prepared to say if they are equally inappropriate for all the suggested sites.

Would something like this be reason to raise a custom mod flag and let our exception handling team take a look at the situation and talk with this user or should I just let it be?

Comment: [Maybe if someone decided to implement this in the actual platform, this would be less of an annoyance!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362417/1079354)

Comment: True. In this case, it's compounded by the fact that many times it's custom close vote, which other users sometimes end up voting with.

Comment: Seriously though - not 100% sure if a flag would get the point across.  It's basically saying that it's OK for moderators to take action against users who post site recommendations in error, whereas site recommendations can *sometimes* be useful.  (Not all the time, not by a long shot, but *sometimes*.)  I don't think that until it bubbles up to the priority of someone's development cycle that we're going to have a clean resolution to this.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, "taking action" sounds a bit strong here. A comment reply by a ♦ linking to one of the meta discussions on how/when to recommend other sites could well be enough.

Comment: @Makoto It wouldn't be my first recommendation either, but there's also a problem with *not* flagging them if the user keeps doing it. After all, the comments will stick and others will think it's ok to make erroneous suggestions (and while we don't penalize it, people should be more careful when recommending other sites in general). So at least the comment should be removed, but a 'No longer needed' flag would suffice in many (if not most) occasions.

Comment: Mod flag one of their posts and explain the behavior.

Answer (score 17):

**TL DR**
So if a user is regularly writing comments recommending users post on another stack exchange site and they do not appear qualified to make that suggestion, by all means do raise a custom mod flag and we can have a word with them.

---

### Conditions for flagging

Unfortunately ([*as now this is confusing*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389191/3956566)), I would encourage you to raise a custom mod flag if you see this type of repeated comment, with the following caveat:

Check the [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956566/yvette-colomb?tab=profile) and see what communities they belong to.

> [image]

- If they don't have a decent reputation on the target site/s they continually recommend, then please do make a custom mod flag. I cringe when I see well meaning users making this type of suggestion, so am happy for community support with this.
- Perhaps include this answer in the flag, so the moderator handling the flag, can see upon what authority you're making the flag (*I don't want people to have these types of flags summarily declined*).

When handling migration flags, generally, I check the flagger's profile for their activity on the target site. I'm not an expert on the other sites. I have had a [fair bit to do with the folk on Code Review](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and will ask them there if they want a question. More often than not they say no. It's up to them, they're the experts on their site. [They don't like it when we migrate off topic questions to their site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bcodereview-se%5D%20is%3Aq).

The active members of potential target sites know if a question is a good fit or if it's a duplicate. It takes a fair bit of time to work out if a question is on topic for that site, by asking mods or high rep users on that site, so unless the flagger is a high rep user or a mod on the target site, I generally decline flags to migrate posts. With the exception if I think it may be a good fit for Code Review and I go and ask them first.

### Leave a comment instead of flagging

The other option is to leave a comment for the user leaving these comments - if you feel brave, you can do so, linking to this answer. If they argue with you, raise a custom mod flag on the comment and let the mods step in.

For clarity, when people are drawn to this post, from
[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/310756):

> - **Don't migrate crap!** Ever. If the question is likely to be closed or deleted on the destination site anyway, don't bother migrating it.
>   Just vote to close it normally and advise the OP of the other site in
>   the comments. If they decide to improve the question, then they can go
>   post it over there, or they can edit their question so it's on-topic
>   on the original site.
> - **Check for cross-posts.** It may be possible, that after hearing about the other site, that the OP may cross-post their question onto
>   the other site. Therefore, check the intended destination site for
>   potential cross-posts before voting to migrate. If it has been
>   cross-posted, vote to close it instead, as cross-posting is prohibited
>   even if the question is on-topic on both sites.
> - **Avoid migrating answered questions.** The point of migration is to send the question to a place where it is on-topic and *can* get
>   answered. If the OP already has an answer, then we've already defeated
>   the purpose of migration and the destination site won't have anything
>   to do with the question. Avoid migrating these questions unless they
>   are of extremely good quality and risk deletion on their current site.
> - **Don't migrate for the sake of migration.** We only migrate questions because they are *off-topic on the original site*. It is
>   perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on multiple sites,
>   but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere, unless the OP
>   requests migration. As a general rule, if someone asks a question
>   *here*, and it's on-topic *here*, it should stay *here*.
> - **Be familiar with the destination site.** If you are not familiar with the destination site, read through its about page and help center
>   thoroughly and *make sure* the question actually belongs there. Don't
>   just look at the name of a site and automatically assume that the
>   question can be asked there. Each site has its own rules, and rules
>   vary greatly across sites.
> - **If you're not sure, don't vote to migrate it.** Let someone else who *is* sure do that, just vote to close it as off-topic, or ask for
>   opinions from the community in a relevant chat room.

I should add, that likewise with migration, sending people off to other sites is still potentially sending poor quality posts there. It's important people are familiar with the target site, what type of questions they accept and whether the question is well formed for that site.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yvette. Just an aside: I’m less concerned with the “migration” angle than with they telling users in general _“foo is not on-topic here”_. I do not believe there even is a migration path from here to [foo]. Actually; I’m pretty sure anything that’s on topic there is on topic here; or almost everything at least. I probably didn’t emphasize the right bits in my question. Your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Since both answers are by mods; I won’t “accept” either. The information and viewpoints will be useful for other users nonetheless.

Comment: @yivi yep - I got that re the migration angle - which is why I added that last sentence - it's still encouraging people to go elsewhere in a way that may not be in the best interest of that person, the target site or even our site. Being on topic elsewhere doesn't automatically preclude a post being off topic here. As for not accepting an answer - that is fine. I've chatted to George about it in our mod room. I have publicly going against another mod - it feels very disloyal and George is a good egg. I do encourage these types of flags, I just hope they are honoured, I guess we will see. :)

Comment: I’ll expand here on something I said to Yvette in the mod room: it’s not probable that an average user is going to know about, let alone have readily internalized the migration guidance. Even if they did it’s pages long. I don’t expect a stack overflow moderator to consult that every time they encounter a migration flag; so I can’t expect a user to do it either. Migration is primarily a “dealing with other” issue and not a binary technological decision. There’s leeway in getting it wrong because the guidance is so expansive I’m surprised when people get it right. I can’t fault for being wrong.

Answer (score -12):

We don't expect Stack Overflow users to be experts of other sites; and counter-intuitively we couldn't judge whether they're right or wrong anyway.  Even in our own migrations, there's an expectation that the target site may reject a question if it's off-topic there, and that's OK.    Since saying "this should be on another site" when it shouldn't is 'wrong', the question is actually: "Should we flag when someone gives bad advice in their comment?".  Put that way, the answer becomes clear:

No, because you're asking moderators to make a value judgment on comments, and we can't adjudicate comments based on value judgments.

That's why the comment flag reasons look like this:

[image]

There is a 'Something Else', but that's generally used to indicate multiple comments needing cleaned up.

A better way to handle it would be to address the comment with why you believe that comment to be in error.  That way if the user flags the post for a moderator to migrate it, we have someone who hopefully knows better than we do to indicate reasons why it may not be a good question to migrate.

Comment: There is the part about being experts on _this_ site. The comments (and close-votes) say the questions are not on-topic here because they relate to certain tag or tags. Plenty of on-topic questions exist for those tags. Does this have any weight?

Comment: @yivi As moderators on this site, we can adjudicate what should be on this site; but my above guidance stands: We don't know if the question should be on [target site] or not, we only know whether or not it belongs on this site.  We can adjudicate postively whether it should be here, but we won't ever be able to say "No, it shouldn't be on [target site]" which is what a flag asking us to delete something because it's "wrong" is asking.

Comment: If I see repeated, ill-advised comments from the same user; I do not believe it's a good strategy to address those as I see them. It would feel like over-engaging, and could end up escalating. I don't believe it's a good strategy at all, and wouldn't recommend it to regular users.

Comment: The comments says "It should be asked there, not here". The "not here" part also concerns me.

Comment: @yivi that's fair. I tried to give something actionable to do so the moderators can see. You don't even need to address the other person in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your advise anyway. I'll keep it in mind.