# Automatically removing comments that aren't *just* "Thank you!" and "+1 Nice Answer!"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

I am aware that we currently have a system in place that removes comments when you flag them as "No Longer Needed" if they meet certain criteria/keywords.

These include comments that contain (as per my research)

- "thanks" and "thank you", and other similar inflections
- "+1"
- ["whathaveyoutried.com"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272171/4909087)

These keywords are necessary but not sufficient to automatically delete a comment as soon as you flag them.
(If I'm not mistaken, the criteria for whether a comment is to be spammed or hammed is determined by a Naive Bayes Classifier, if the system is the same as what is described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/4909087).)

I consider it good that what's currently in place is at a state where it can accurately remove such comments on its own to alleviate the garbage that mods have to sift through themselves, but I believe it can be made better still.

While there are a ton of comments expressing gratitude and appreciation, there are just as many *noisy* comments responding to those, with "you're welcome!", or "no worries!", or "sure shugga" :|

Additionally, the current system does not really cater to *all* forms of gratitude, comments like "Awesome solution!", or "This is fantastic!" are still far from being automatically detected and removed as unnecessary.

Thus, the goal of this post is to request that this system be extended to cater to a broader set of keywords/terms, so this is a feature request of sorts.

Suggested/recommended extensions include

- "Much appreciated", "cheers", "awesome", and other salutations that are similar to "thank you" (see above)
- comments that *respond* to thanks, such as "no problem", "no worries", or, "you're welcome"
- comments that say "-1" without really giving constructive criticism, as these could just be seen as inflammatory and encourage ill-will and retaliatory action.

I believe this would be a useful extension to the current system in place, and would result in more cleanup with less headache. What are your thoughts?

Comment: There are several bots that do this, they post links into a chat room.  Surely their authors are receptive to suggestions.

Comment: @HansPassant I see. Those are great initiatives, and I really hope the Stack Overflow team would consider adapting/extending the current system with them. If this is a part of the main system to begin with, one can remove the latency period and bypass the need for moderator intervention completely.

Comment: _removes comments if they meet certain criteria/keywords._ I believe it gives an error message when you try to comment starting with `+/- 1`

Comment: @SurajRao Yes, but there are a lot of such comments floating around from SO's golden days, before they outlawed comments containing content like that.

Comment: There is no system *from Stack Overflow* that auto-deletes comments. The system by Andy has been disabled when they were elected moderator. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354719/should-moderators-run-automated-bots-under-their-accounts

Comment: This could be an extension in [Heat Detector/SOCVFinder](https://stackapps.com/questions/7001/heat-detector-analysing-comments-to-find-heat)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm talking about automatic removal when you flag them as no longer needed.

Comment: Right, that wasn’t clear, nor does that apply to the comments that Andy’s classified flagged.

Comment: @MartijnPieters my apologies, I should've certainly made that clearer. The reason I linked to Andy's post is because I was under the impression that had an influence on the system currently in place for automatically removing comments that are flagged without them having to sit in the moderator review queue. Once again, apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: The SO system hasn’t changed; it’s still just a keyword match when a comment is flagged. Keyword in comment -> lower the threshold for deletion. Enough flags for deletion (threshold met)? -> delete the comment.

Comment: How about having 2 types of comments: temporary and permanent. Temporary will be the default and they will be removed after some time (let's say 2 days)?

Comment: @Oleg That's a nice alternative, one I fear would be even harder to get clearance for. Still, one can dream.

Comment: What about giving a warning for the comment poster "Are you really sure that this should be posted? Our comments are not for ...."

Comment: @Oleg I'm afraid that it will generate a lot of unnecessary comments marked as temporary. "_Marking a comment as temporary does not exempt it from following SE rules_".

Comment: @user202729 The rules will remain the same, and people will make the same comments. People who make "Thank you" comments will continue to just make them and they will be automatically removed after 2 days. If you have an important comment to make about an answer you will need to do an extra step every time you want to make a permanent comment. I don't see how this will generate more unnecessary comments than we have now, unfortunately I agree with COLDSPEED; this is not going to happen so I'm not even going to bother with making a proper feature-request.

Comment: @user202729 people are already certain they *want* to post the comment at that point. Nag messages are not the right tool to get people to reconsider.

Comment: @Gimby Except those who don't read the help center... nevermind, they won't read anyway. No problem.