# Ban boilerplate comments on downvoting as well ( or at least make them one vote deletes )

Tags: feature-request, comments, word-filter

Boilerplate comments that say things like *"read the FAQ"*, *"show your work"*, etc are banned, I think we should ban the various comments about down voting as well. *"downvoter explain"*, *"why the downvote"*, *"@Downvoter care to comment?"* etc. Because it is proven that in practice, such [comments are non-constructive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post/37123#37123) regardless of the popular sentiment expressed by those that never down vote to begin with.

The goal is to force a little bit more effort into getting a **specific** thing they could improve. If they genuinely want constructive feedback this should not be considered an onerous requirement to put some thought and effort into asking for suggestions for improvement. Other heuristics like length and other things could weed out a majority of the low effort complaining for complaining sake comments and still encourage people to ask for constructive feedback.

They just want to complain will just have one more thing to complain about, no fixing them so why try?

Comment: While your seething tone is enough to boil water for tea, I find myself *wholly* agreeing with this...

Comment: Why the downvotes? :(

Comment: It might be necessary for some of the relevant keywords to simply go to the one flag delete list, rather than trying to find all of the variations to prevent them from being posted, due to how much variation there is in comments like these.

Comment: @Servy - the `@Downvoter` has gotten very popular lately, that is what prompted this post.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Yeah, just saying that there are enough different wordings of the comment (with the same basic premise) that trying to ban all of them may not be feasible.  You may need to prevent posting of the few most common variations, and then add a few new keywords to the one-flag-delete list to cover the rest.

Comment: @Servy - yeah, simple detection of any variation of the word `downvoter` and `comment`, `explain`, or `reason` and a prompt that that is not allowed or making them single vote removable would go a long ways to make the site better. Every one of these comments is a passive aggressive attempt at public shaming at best and in many peoples opinion is the worst kind of violation of the "Be Nice" policy.

Comment:  care to comment?

Comment: @Mysticial - variations on Metaphone exist for a reason.

Comment: "I did not downvote, but I can see someone else may have thought this was not a useful question." (IOW: hey, maybe you are in a foul mood now so let's make it clear I did not downvote. (Yet.) So dontcha yell at *me*.)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson What's Metaphone and how is that supposed to catch all the unicode variants? A quick google search didn't reveal anything useful.

Comment: The link you posted as evidence that these comments are non-constructive... the top answer argues that they are, indeed, constructive? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252910/3033053

Comment: general consensus is not really valid on the internet, and empirical evidence says it they are not.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson If you have a way to detect all variations of a word, I think this question would be interested in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096634/regular-expression-preg-quote-symbols-are-not-detected

Comment: @Mysticial - I wrote a phonetic "bad word" filter back in the day that used a highly modified Metaphone implementation, it pissed off a lot of angry tweens when they could no longer use 1337 speak to get around the naive brain dead filter I replaced. So unicode variants are not a problem.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson TBH, that sounds like something you should either publish or maybe even try to sell as a product. AFAICT, this is a hard problem that nobody but you is claiming to have solved. Can it even detect ASCII art? (not that it applies to SO comments)

Comment: Not sure if my SQL is perfect, but the [most common comments containing the text "downvote"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/843693/recent-comments-containing-downvote) are mostly for http://idownvotedbecau.se/ comments.  That, and a bunch of variations on "why the downvote"

Comment: I feel like noting that whatever is done here either needs to not apply to meta, or be adjusted to account for the fact that meta will often be talking about votes in ways that are actually appropriate.

Comment: @Mysticial - yes, you can map any sequence of chars. there was also a "phrase" filter that worked as a superset of the single word filter.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson What about a captcha image represented as ASCII art? I'm not trying to doubt your abilities, but you can see where I'm trying to go with this...

Comment: @Mysticial - no this was for pronounceable words as text not images

Comment: Though they may be a minority, [there are constructive comments that mention downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253025/2751851). Suppose that I want to write "I see this post has been downvoted. How can I improve it?". According to this proposal, would I (a) be able to do it, (b) have to reword it to remove the word "downvote" and get past the filter, or (c) have to give up on the comment?

Comment: @duplode There's definitely a lot of ways to say "downvoter" without actually using the word "downvoter" in whatever unicode or phonetic forms assuming that Jarrod does have 100% detection rate for them. "Person who made my score go down.", "User who made the number next to my post decrease.", "You who clicked on the triangle that's below the number.", "Hey buddy, the one who has an orange arrow below a grey arrow."

Comment: @duplode - that is kind of the point, *How can I improve my question?* is enough without the word downvote. Regardless, longer phrases like your examples should indicate a more thoughtful request than the snarky passive aggressive *"downvoter explain"* which would be more constructive. Maybe even suggest *"How can I specifically make my question more answerable?"*, effort in effort out.

Comment: consider adjusting the proposal with some length limit for banned comments, similarly to how it is done for banning ["+1" comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283953/839601 "'dropping this restriction for comments that exceed 120 characters in length'") (on a related note @duplode I wouldn't mind if comments like in your example were blocked: "I see this post has been downvoted. How can I improve it?" is way too trivial, shows no effort and looks quite superfluous)

Comment: Is there evidence that the rate of such comments is too high to flag them to mods manually? If not, this is a non-issue.

Comment: i mean... what would you flag them as? they're requesting clarification.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev As far as I know, mods cannot handle all custom flags in due time as it is. The less "no longer needed" flags in the way, the better for them.

Comment: @E_net4 Yeah, but since automated comment filters are inflexible, easily circumventable and prone to false positives, hitting one of which is downright insulting, we better make damn sure they would do massively more good than harm.

Comment: @Mysticial Given that I'm already used to [paraphrasing "duplicate"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344519/2751851), having to do it for "downvote" as well won't be too much worse :D

Comment: @JarrodRoberson If the spirit of the proposal is getting people to think before they write, rather than making a boilerplate complaint out of reflex, I'm largely okay with it.

Comment: I kind of hate it when rules like these are imposed. Sure we are a place where we can vote up and down, but do we really need to impose rules like that? In the end sometimes it is wise to let people react and let off some steam. And yes, these kind of comments are generally useless, if not just for the fact that the downvoter is unlikely to visit the page again. But hey, let people find out themselves.

Comment: @gnat In a real comment to a post on the main site, I'd likely use more careful wording. In any case, I'm not sure I get the objection. If I have genuinely no clue about what's wrong with my post, what else could I add to such a comment that wouldn't be superfluous? And exactly how showing effort matters in this specific case?

Comment: Wait, you're using a question on which the consensus (as shown by votes) is clearly *"These comments are constructive"* to argue that *"These comments are not constructive"*?

Comment: In my experience, in vast majority of instances where I asked for reason of the downvotes, I received a constructive feedback explaining how should I improve the question. Banning something that helps improve quality of content on SO sounds like a really stupid idea.

Comment: you've only done that once in the past year, and it didn't result in an edit on your question.

Comment: If you can make a case for these comments, please also do so for useless comments like "You're welcome", and "no problem". [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365273/automatically-removing-comments-that-arent-just-thank-you-and-1-nice-ans)

Comment: Why the upvotes? upvoter please explain???

Comment: @KevinB If I were to ask about a downvote and received feedback, I would probably improve the answer, delete the comment asking about clarification, and flag the other comment as obsolete. Searching comments to prove a point is worthless. After all, [comments are ephemeral](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130990/302165).

Comment: that’s great, however you and I aren’t representative of the whole.

Comment: The voting history of those against this idea is quite telling.

Comment: (as is said history of those for it i suppose)

Comment: comments can be searched using this: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/151786/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=wait&UserId=130127

Comment: @KevinB I was responding to *"you've only done that once in the past year (...)"*. You can't possibly know that, since other comments may have been deleted after becoming obsolete. In short: you're basing your argument on a probably incomplete dataset.

Comment: *"The voting history of those against this idea is quite telling"* <- And this is just a plain *Ad Hominem*. Argue against the idea, not against the users.

Comment: @CássioRenan Sure, but when users are claiming to have broad evidence through experience that asking "why the downvote" is a good idea, disputing that evidence existing and proving it doesn't exist is useful. In this case the user has used said comment maybe 20 times, and it only resulted in positive feedback maybe twice.

Comment: @KevinB "the voting history of those against this idea is quite telling" What doe sit tell you since you have no idea what the voting history of anyone is, since you're not an employee?

Comment: @TylerH you can see how many, where, and in what direction users vote in their summary.

Comment: @KevinB I still don't see what it tells you since you only see aggregate numbers and have no idea of whether they were voting on Jon Skeet posts or spam posts or anywhere in between.

Comment: Yes, but you can see whether or not they routinely cast votes at all and whether or not they avoid downvoting.

Comment: There is an uber-meta post that is very similar: [One-flag deletion of "@downvoter", "Why downvote?" and similar comments](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/175394)

Comment: @feelingunwelcome surely the solution to the public shaming / down voter revealing their identity problem is to allow those who have down voted to leave an _anonymous_ comment.

Answer (score 17):

> Because it is proven that in practice, such [comments are non-constructive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253201/1340389). **regardless of the popular sentiment expressed in the most up voted answer to that question.**

That's not how this works.  That's not how any of this works.  If you disagree with the "popular sentiment," you have to explain why.  You can't just categorically state that it's wrong and then treat that as an absolute fact.

Asking the reasons for a downvote is entirely reasonable unless the post is pure gibberish or otherwise blatantly worthless.  It's the only way a person can get better at writing questions and answers.

> If they genuinely want constructive feedback this should not be considered an onerous requirement to put some thought and effort into asking for suggestions for improvement.

If I get downvoted, and I don't know why I was downvoted, how am I supposed to "put more effort" into my comment asking why?  Should I pad it out with a sob story about how my dog died and I was having a bad day, and that's why I must have written something badly that caused you to downvote my post?  Because that just seems like it would add noise.  I don't see how it would make things materially better.

Or is it just the two-word phrase "downvoter explain" that you disapprove of?  Frankly, I don't understand why anyone would care one way or the other about that.  Unlike (for example) the "what have you tried" epidemic that got nuked a while ago, there is generally only one person who posts these comments for any given post, namely the person who got downvoted.  We don't see [massive piles of comments on a single post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172758/275243) unless they get into an argument with someone else.

If one of these disagreements turns into a huge thread, sure, flag that and the mods will delete it or migrate it to chat.  Otherwise, it's not worth having a separate policy for these comments.

Comment: I personally don't ask anymore why people down vote, people down vote for the most random things.  IE, they don't like the language you asked about, or they just felt like it, etc.  Asking people to justify their votes where they already haven't just adds unneeded noise to an already noisy stack.  on the movies stack i tend to flag these sorts of comments as "no longer needed" as they are overly chatty

Comment: @DForck42: You obviously have every right to do that.  But why do you care one iota whether people "clutter" their own posts with a *single* comment?

Comment: The desire to ask about the down votes is palpable.

Comment: In most cases where i respond to such a comment, it rarely ever results in any form of improvement to the post or useful discussion.  But i'm of course just 1 data point.

Comment: @KevinB: In most cases where people post comments of any kind, it rarely results in any form of improvement (and "useful discussion" is not the purpose of comments).

Comment: i mean, it is, if said "useful discussion" is for the purpose of improving the post.

Comment: @KevinB: In several years on this site, I think I've seen that happen once or twice as a result of a "useful discussion" such as the one which we are having now.

Comment: From my experience, it is not most, not half and not some: *almost every time* I have responded to a request for a reason it was not constructive: The OP just aggressively defends their current question instead of addressing the issue. I now read these sorts of comments as "I'm angry I was downvoted and want to argue with someone about why my post is great as is. Anyone willing?"

Comment: Hey, let's all just take a step back and keep in mind that all downvotes occur because [Tim lost his keys...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397)

Comment: @TemporalWolf - that is the majority of the cases in practice when the comment is *downvoter explain* or other terse passive aggressive comments. They just want someone to rail against, they want a **name** and are completely unconcerned about the **reason**.

Comment: when a downvote is unjustified/unexplained, you generally get some counter upvotes because other users also think it's unfair. So downvoting for mysterious reasons and not explaining them backfires, generating pity/counter upvotes. Downvoting a badly formatted/overcomplex solution often goes without saying.

Comment: 'It's the only way a person can get better at writing questions and answers' - has the help/tour been offline, then?

Comment: @MartinJames People aren't perfect. They can read the entire help section and tour and still write an answer that someone else thinks is bad or needs work. We don't have any control over how other people react. That's why successful communication is important in the success of a population.

Answer (score 4):

In vast majority of the cases where I asked what prompts downvotes on my question/answer, I received honest feedback and advice explaining how to fix the question, or at least what's wrong with it.

Your proposal to ban a feature that is [helpful by consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252910/607407) and by my experience seems absolutely unfounded from my perspective. I think you should have brought some hard data supporting your stance before even proposing this idea.

So, the reasons not to ban:

- From my anecdotal experience these comments can help improve posts, as they signal to other users viewing the post that you *do care* about improving it
- The consensus in the linked question is overwhelmingly against your idea
- As indicated in comments, this is hard or even impossible to implement
- We already have enough backlogs in review, no need to create another queue

Reasons to ban:

- Please edit your question to add some?

And, I'd like to stress once more: **If you stress that general consensus is invalid, you need to back that opinion with hard data.**

Comment: Can you provide examples where this occurred to your posts?

Comment: I don't really know how to search comments network-wide, and even if I knew how to do that, I'm not sure if I'd remember all of the wording variations that I used. Regardless, my experience is not the only point of this answer - it's actually the least relevant, since it's so subjective.

Comment: They're in your profile. I've been through about a years worth of comments so far and have found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817860/can-i-use-qt-thread-id-to-create-unique-cache-for-every-thread/45818158#comment78595774_45818158)

Comment: @KevinB beat me to it; [I am not seeing any evidence of your claims of 100% positive feedback either.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607407/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-zato?tab=activity&sort=comments) So you need to back up your claim with evidence, not that there seems to be any. Finding people complaining and attacking about down votes when people give a reason in a comment is easy on just the front page any given hour of the day. People actually making changes because of them, practically impossible.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I am active across the network, not just on SO. Tell me how to search the comments and I will make some pretty graph. Also I said majority, not 100% - the fact that you're intentionally misinterpreting what I said makes me doubt that you're interested in finding any data at all.

Comment: @TomášZato have at it: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/151786/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=wait&UserId=130127

Answer (score 2):

> Because it is proven that in practice, such [comments are non-constructive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253201/177800) regardless of the popular sentiment expressed in the most up voted answer to that question.

Your answer that you linked to currently has a -3 score and the best answer there has a score of 275 and disagrees with your position. I think you should address their points. I don't see that you've done that.

I'm unconvinced this is a good idea.