# "Dear downvoter..."

Tags: discussion, comments

I see comments like this one scattered around occasionally:

> Dear person that downvoted this question about 7 hours ago, if you're going to downvote a question that, based on the number of upvotes and favorites, has obviously helped multiple peoples' understanding of `####`, including my own, at least add a comment as to why...

(actual comment text, minus topic name)

If someone's already downvoted and provided no feedback in the form of commentary, answers, or close votes, they probably aren't coming back. The only people who will see this are the people who hadn't voted yet at the time it was written.

These kinds of comment attract comment-upvotes, but I think that has more to do with agreeing with the spirit of the comment than wanting it to bubble-to-the-top because it's legitimately useful, which it isn't. Since these are likely to appear on posts that are well-received *except* for the unexplained downvote, there's likely to be content-related discussion and this comment bubbling-up can obscure that.

Should these be flagged as "no longer needed"? I don't think they serve a useful purpose, especially on older posts (but I don't want to go around flagging OP comments without community approval either).

Comment: I would personnaly flag it as *no longed needed* because it's never needed

Comment: _"No longer needed"_ is fine. I usually get my flags on such comments marked as helpful.

Comment: Based on the title expected a love letter. Utterly disappointed ...

Comment: Addressing the "letter" at a specific downvoter isn't helpful, nor is using post score to challenge the downvote. Gently and earnestly asking for feedback from other users in general can be constructive, though that is a contentious matter -- cf. [this recent Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366421/2751851), which currently has a +41/-48 vote split.